# How to change few css class on button in jQuery by timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When document is ready, there is a button that gets a new class names `frame1`. I want to set another class on this button after two seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#button').addClass('frame1')
    }, 2000);
});
```

I want to add another class 'frame2' after two seconds if that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add a class every coule of seconds until you have no more classes to add, you could use an interval and then clear it when the classes have all been added:

```
var group = [ 'whiteFG', 'redBG' ];
var intvl= setInterval(function(){
    group.length 
        ? $("#foo").addClass(group.pop()) 
        : clearInterval(intvl) ;
}, 2000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EvXPy/

Or you could simply iterate over your array of class names and set timeouts from there:

```
$(['redBG','whiteFG']).each(function(i,o){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#foo").addClass(o);
    }, i * 2000 );
});​​​​​​​​
```

Note that the first effect will run immediately since `i` is equal to the index of `0`, meaning the timeout happens instantly. If you want this to be delayed, you can increment `i` as you see fit before multiplying by 2000.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EvXPy/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  setTimeout(frame1(), 2000);
});
function frame1() {
  $('#button').addClass('frame1');
  setTimeout(frame2(), 2000);
}
function frame2() {
  $('#button').addClass('frame2');
}
```

Or you could do it this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#button').addClass('frame1')
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#button').addClass('frame2')
  }, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $('#button').addClass('frame1');
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function () {
        $('#button').addClass('frame2');
}, 2000);
```

### UPDATE:

If you want to check whether class is exists then do this way.

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    $('#button').addClass('frame1');
    if($('#button').hasClass('frame1')) { 
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#button').removeClass('frame1').addClass('frame2'); 
        }, 2000); 
    }   
}, 2000);
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/rat8K/)**

Comment: Doesn't work! I tried that to. Program use just second class, like first isn't there, so i tried this to:
$(document).ready(function () { 
    setTimeout(function () {
            $('#button').addClass('frame1')
        }, 2000);
    if($('#button').hasClass('frame1'))
    {
      setTimeout(function () {
            $('#button').addClass('frame2').removeClass('frame1');
        }, 2000);
    }
    });
But does'n work :/